# What is this Star Trek TOS device with the ribbon of small colored squares on top?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, technology

[image]

I'm fairly sure I've seen this object at least twice in the rec room during series 1, where I assumed it was some kind of futuristic game like the 3D chess or space checkers which also happened to be in that room. The "ribbon of colored squares" even reminded me of Connect Four for some reason.

But in TOS: "Who Mourns for Adonais?" we see it suddenly appear on the bridge (as shown above), for only one scene if I remember correctly, and there was no mention of it in dialogue. Since they brought it up here as part of their efforts to find a countermeasure for Apollo's energy field, it must do *something* useful. So now I'm curious enough to ask: **Is there any canon evidence as to what this device is or what it's for?**

Comment: I'm thinking... futuristic abacus.

Comment: @JackBNimble Sounds more plausible than Connect Four.

Comment: Wasn't this also used as a court stenographer's console in Wolf in The Fold? It's been a while...

Comment: Possibly a chicken soup dispenser. Were there any 3rd grade technicians in any of those episodes?

Comment: @MajorStackings No, they were in stasis at the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## It is probably a General Purpose Computer

[Ex Astris Scientia](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/reused_props_padds.htm) labels it as a 'TOS Desktop Computer', seen in the recreation room in *Conscience of the King*:

[image]

Unfortunately it doesn't explain it's functionality!

This fan-made image shows the computer, also in the recreation room:

[image]

So it does evidently have *some* recreational value.  The fact that we see the same (or a similar) device indicates that it also has some functional value as well.

However, I have come across [this site](http://tosgraphics.yuku.com/topic/371/TOS-Computer-props-REVISED-and-in-HD#.VejpffQnqyw) which labels it as the **'Type 3 Alpha' Computer**.  The site focuses mainly on describing the appearance of the computer, however, in the image shown in the question (from *Who Mourns for Adonis?**), the sit explains that:

> It was the type 3 computer operated by Lt. Leslie that helped Sulu
>   determine where Apollo’s power source was located.

This 'Type 3' Computer is seen in the following episodes:

The type 3 computer appears in these episodes:

> 13 - Conscience of the King
>
> 20 - Alternative Factor
>
> 23 – A Taste of Armageddon
>
> 27 – Errand of Mercy
>
> 33 – Who Mourns for Adonais?
>
> 34 – Amok Time
>
> 42 – Trouble with Tribbles
>
> 48 – Immunity Syndrome
>
> 50 – By Any Other Name
>
> 53 – The Ultimate Computer
>
> 54 – The Omega Glory
>
> 60 – And the Children Shall Lead
>
> 63 – The Empath
>
> 66 – Day of the Dove
>
> 68 – Wink of an Eye

This type of computer is seen in the recreation room, personal quarters and on the bridge, so it's a versatile little unit!  It is also seen in *The Omega Glory* as part of Dr McCoy's medical equipment.

My conclusion would therefore be that ***this is a general-purpose computer***.  Sorry if it's a bit of a cop-out answer, but considering all the purposes it is used for throughout *TOS*, it seems the most likely answer.

Comment: Heh, Star Trek laptop